# How do you get rid of blue numbers

Tags: mesh

[image]

blue numbers that keep appearing when I resize vertices help

[image]

Comment: You probably have edge length info ticked on or an addon is doing some openGL drawing over your object (Archimesh, or Archipack for example). Anyway, an image would be helpful to confirm.

Comment: @Timaroberts There uploaded a pic, how to I unselect whatever that is tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot it appears that you have enabled *edge length* under [mesh display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/mesh_display.html#mesh-display).

To enable/ disable this option, open the properties panel with <kbd>N</kbd> and select/ deselect *length* under *edge info*.

[image]